# Code structuring - How to include a file (JS, PHP, etc...) into HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

how are you?

I want to structure my code as carefully as possible, but I don’t know how to do it. In a single file, I have PHP, JS and HTML code and I was wondering if it was possible to separate the contents by including their "path" in the html code.

For example, how I can separate the php code as well as the js code:

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   { js code }
   { php code }
</body>
</html>```

Thank you in advance for the information I would receive
````

Comment: This is too broad a question to be on-topic on stackoverflow.  Depending on the size of the project I would always use a template-engine to seperate display and business logic; if the project is small Fatimas answer is a viable start.

Answer (score -1):

You can use '.php' file as default then just put html into that

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <script src="file.js"></script>
     <?php include('file.php') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Waaaaw, thanks a lot

Comment: Usually javascript is loaded in the `<head>` section with `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`